# Improve heap memory usage reporting in Windows application

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management

In using the following code, I have observed that increases in memory usage are registered fairly quickly in the variable members of ***[PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***, but as memory is freed in a process that continues to run, it appears that decreasing memory usage does not seem to register

```
time_t GetMemUsage(void)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    DWORD processID = GetCurrentProcessId();

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
    GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize;
}
```

Using Task Manager, I can see almost immediately a physical memory size change (smaller) after *terminating* a process, but freeing memory as a process runs does not register.  (Even after a substantial delay before calling the above function.)

I am not sure if my observations are due to the way `free()` works.  (i.e. maybe it does not notify the OS memory is freed), or if Windows is just slow in registering it to the `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS` struct.

In any case, is anyone aware of a better technique to obtain more timely and *accurate* reports of actual memory usage within (or for) a running process?

I have also tried looking at `pmc.WorkingSetSize` and `pmc.PagefileUsage` with same results.

Comment: Getting memory from the OS and getting memory with eg. `malloc()` are different things.  Ultimately, your process gets memory from the OS when it needs to and `malloc()` etc. gives pieces of it to your program when it allocates things... but `malloc()` could give you another part of a page your process already has (maybe from an earlier allocation), or reuse pages from an earlier allocation that's been freed already.

Comment: @Dmitri - In my testing, I have allocated blocks of memory large enough that Windows has been required to provide more to the process.  I can see this when I look at the variables provided by `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`.  My problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to see when the memory is given back.  I am looking for a way to observe a _reduction_ in memory usage as well as an increase.

Comment: That's the thing... it might not *be* given back.  If you try another large allocation after freeing the old one though, you might not see another increase as the old pages may be reused.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on here.

1. Memory managers, tend to keep memory around after you've freed it.  The theory is that you're likely to need more memory soon, and giving you back memory you've used recently is cheaper than getting more memory from the operating system.  Thus, from the operating system's perspective, your program is still using memory you've freed.
2. Working set size is an indirect measure of the memory your program is using.  The operating system determines the working set size based on memory demand from your program *and* based on memory pressure from everything else running on the system.  As your program starts to use more memory, the operating system will (typically) quickly grow the process's working set to accommodate it.  If your program releases a bunch of memory back to the operating system, that doesn't necessarily mean the OS will trim the process's working set size.  In fact, if there's plenty of RAM available, it probably won't bother.  But if lots of other processes need memory, and you start to reach the capacity of your RAM, then the OS will start trimming the working set of processes that have more than they currently need.
3. It looks like your code sample is reporting *peak* working set size rather than the current working set size.  The peak tells you the largest working set size the process reached during its lifetime, even if the current working set is much smaller.

Comment: In the final sentence of my post I said I had also tried pmc.WorkingSetSize and pmc.PagefileUsage.  Nonetheless, your points under 1 & 2. are well stated.  Thanks.  Here's the money question: Are you _aware of a better technique to obtain more timely and accurate reports of actual memory usage_???

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "actual memory usage."  It's not that simple of a question.  RAM usage?  Virtual address space usage?  Do you want to count memory that you've returned to the memory manager even if the memory manager hasn't returned it to the OS?  How do you want to measure fragmentation?

Comment: I am looking for a way to force Windows to show a change in physical heap memory upon my freeing it from within a process.  Dimitri's observation is correct ( _That's the thing... it might not be given back_ ), the memory might not be given back from an OS perspective.  Is there a way, or a method that can be used to _persuade_ the OS to immediately return freed memory such that I can see it using `pmc.WorkingSetSize` or `pmc.PagefileUsage` or similar?

Comment: I'm not sure what "physical heap memory" is, since the heap is usually on top of virtual memory.  Nevertheless, it's not the OS you need to persuade; it's your program, specifically, the memory manager your program is using.  That's likely the beast that's not returning the memory to the OS.

Comment: I think of C# has having an _active memory manager_.  In C/C++, With the exception of OS macro memory management activities, _I_ am the memory manager, at least at the executable level.  (i.e. I am responsible to call the `free()` function, close files, close handles, etc.)  But at the OS level, I wonder if there is, for example, a Windows call to tickle the OS to release all memory that is not being used explicitly at this point.  And by the way, I agree with you, _it's not that simple of a question_.  I realize that now.

Comment: As far as the OS is concerned, `malloc()` and `free()` are part of your program.  At some point `malloc()` asks the OS for memory, but `free()` doesn't typically give it back to the OS.  So it's not a matter of tickling the OS in order to get your freed memory reflected in the stats.  It's a matter of convincing `free()` to actually return memory to the OS.  There's no standard for that.  And, in most cases, you really don't want to do that anyway.